C# Godot Resource failing to Cast to Godot.Resource to My Custom one
Godot 4.3 Mono
I have the resource below
using Godot;
using System;

[GlobalClass]
public partial class EffectAccepter : Resource
{
    [Export] public AHeatableStrategy HeatableStrategy { get; set; }
    // Can add more effects to accept easily here, and insert strategies needed
    public ABoardObject BoardObject { get; set; }

    public EffectAccepter Initialize(ABoardObject boardObject)
    {
        BoardObject = boardObject;
        return this;
    }

    public void Accept(AEffect effect)
    {
        if (effect is HeatEffect heatEffect)
        {
            HeatableStrategy?.Accept(heatEffect, BoardObject);
        }
    }

}


With the sub export being:
using Godot;

[GlobalClass]

public abstract partial class AHeatableStrategy : Resource
{
    public abstract void Accept(HeatEffect heatEffect, ABoardObject boardObject);

}

The subclasses of the abstract classes are detected in the editor and I can properly provide an implemented version
And EffectAccepter is [Export]ed in another class:
    [Export] public EffectAccepter EffectAccepter { get; private set; }

This all works perfectly, even when the code executes the proper Strategy is set and functioning BUT I get an error during Godot starting up the game:

Unable to cast object of type 'Godot.Resource' to type 'EffectAccepter' c# godot

Does anyone know why my resource throws an error?
I have this pattern setup in other classes and it works like a charm, but then in this particular case it fails.

I restarted my computer and it worked. How could I forget the basics.
